# How to build class to manage the output of search index query with JSON document in cloudant

Tags: java, search, indexing, cloudant

I followed the sample class Animal at `https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/blob/88202a1bd7b9b04d96c4b7b8498a1b8f7f99c9e5/src/test/java/com/cloudant/tests/Animal.java`

I successfully managed search index query by this class. I suppose that i have a document with JSON format in cloudant as:

```
{
  "_id": "web",
  "_rev": "11-b1d0e315272a87c2549df4004d836049",
  "min_weight": 40,
  "max_weight": 65,
  "min_length": 1,
  "max_length": 2.2,
  "attributeCollection": {
    "attributeArray": [
      {
        "updateable": false,
        "lookup": "issuetype",
        "issueAttributeDefinitionId": 13,
        "attributeType": 1,
        "name": "web issue",
        "value": [
          "Improper Neutralization of Input During Web Page Generation"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

My question is how to build a Java class to manage the search index output for this documents. Particularly, how to manage set of attributes as "attributeCollection", "attributeArray", ..."name", "value"

Comment: You create an Attribute class with the listed fields.  In your Animal class, you'll have a List of Attribute objects.

Comment: @Gilbert i did it but it doest work. It can solve for "_id", "_rev", "min_weght",.. but it shows errors in "attributeCollection" and so on.

Comment: I don't understand.  Is your JSON parser **automatically** creating Java objects, or are you having trouble mapping the output of your JSON parser to Java objects **that you have manually created**?

Comment: Thanks you, I have trouble to understand the output of search query index. In this case, the return of search query index for this document is JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your last few Stack Overflow posts I think you have a couple of options:

1) If you define your `issue` class as you did in your previous post you can perform a different kind of search in Java to just return those fields in your issue class as follows:

```
SearchResult<issue> issues=db.search("attributes/by_name_value")
    .limit(10).includeDocs(false)
    .querySearchResult("name:\"web*\"", issue.class);

for (int i = 0; i < issues.getRows().size(); i++) {
    SearchResult<issue>.SearchResultRow row = issues.getRows().get(i);
    System.out.println(row.getId());
    System.out.println(row.getFields().getName());             
    System.out.println(row.getFields().getValue());
}
```

Note: this calls `querySearchResult` instead of `query` and `include_docs` is false.

2) If you need to return the entire document then you need to create classes that match your JSON. Your classes should look something like this:

**Issue2**

```
public class Issue2 {

    private String id;
    private Integer min_weight;
    // TODO: other fields
    private AttributeCollection attributeCollection;

    public Issue2() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getMin_weight() {
        return min_weight;
    }

    public void setMin_weight(Integer min_weight) {
        this.min_weight = min_weight;
    }

    public AttributeCollection getAttributeCollection() {
        return attributeCollection;
    }

    public void setAttributeCollection(AttributeCollection attributeCollection) {
        this.attributeCollection = attributeCollection;
    }
```

}

**AttributeCollection**

```
public class AttributeCollection {

    private Attribute[] attributeArray;

    public Attribute[] getAttributeArray() {
        return attributeArray;
    }

    public void setAttributeArray(Attribute[] attributeArray) {
        this.attributeArray = attributeArray;
    }
}
```

**Attribute**

```
public class Attribute {

    private String name;
    private String value[];
    // TODO: other fields

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String[] getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String[] value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the previous search call (with Issue2 class):

```
List<Issue2> issues=db.search("attributes/by_name_value")
    .limit(10).includeDocs(true)
    .query("name:\"web*\"", Issue2.class);

for (int i = 0; i < issues.size(); i++) {
    Issue2 row = issues.get(i);
    System.out.println("min_weight = " + row.getMin_weight());
    if (row.getAttributeCollection() != null && row.getAttributeCollection().getAttributeArray() != null) {
        for (int j=0; j<row.getAttributeCollection().getAttributeArray().length; j++) {
            String name = row.getAttributeCollection().getAttributeArray()[i].getName();
            String[] values = row.getAttributeCollection().getAttributeArray()[i].getValue();
            System.out.println(name);
            if (values != null) {
                for(String value: values) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's so great! thanks you. I still want to ask you "the output of search query index is not JSON right?"

Comment: The output from Cloudant is JSON, but the java driver converts that JSON into instances of your Java classes. That's why your Java classes have to match your JSON structure.

Comment: I added min_weight as an example on how to add your other fields.